# cannot find symbol import com.example.androiddata.databinding.FragmentDetailBindingImpl;

Tags: android, kotlin

why i am receiving this error ? cannot find symbol **import com.example.androiddata.databinding.FragmentDetailBindingImpl;** i am new in android studio, and i connect my android studio in my web api, (django rest framework (online)) so I don't have a clue where to look at.

i followed the tutorial from linkedlearning, and i download the code, when i apply my web api to the android studio, i receive this error,

this is my **AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.example.androiddata">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
                android:name=".SettingsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.example.androiddata.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/main_title">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my global.kit

```
package com.example.androiddata

const val LOG_TAG = "monsterLogging"

const val WEB_SERVICE_URL = "https://myurl****.com/"
```

my SettingsActivity

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        }
    }
}
```

my monster_data.json

```
[
  {"Sequence": 10, "Description": "Grade 1", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 20, "Description": "Grade 2", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 30, "Description": "Grade 3", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 40, "Description": "Grade 4", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 50, "Description": "Grade 5", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 60, "Description": "Grade 6", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 70, "Description": "Grade 7", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 80, "Description": "Grade 8", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 90, "Description": "Grade 9", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 100, "Description": "Grade 10", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 110, "Description": "Grade 11", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 120, "Description": "Grade 12", "Status": "Active"},
  {"Sequence": 130, "Description": "College", "Status": "Active"}
]
```

this is the error

[image]

this my android file

[image]

this is my fragment_detail.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_item_background">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.selectedMonster.monsterName}"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="Mingle"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:price="@{viewModel.selectedMonster.price}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/purchaseButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/purchaseButton"
            tools:text="$0.19 / each"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/purchaseButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/priceText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:text="Purchase"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/monsterImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.selectedMonster.imageUrl}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/purchaseButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/descriptionText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            tools:src="@drawable/monster01"
            tools:contentDescription="Monster name"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.selectedMonster.description}"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ratingLabel"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="Mingle excels at doing twice the work in half the time, with pinpoint accuracy.  These skills serve her well in her role as Senior Data Analyst for an international cloud computing company. She's also got a penchant for ballroom dance, line dancing, and pretty much any kind of activity that lets her groove to music."/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ratingLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/scariness_rating"/>

    <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rating="@{viewModel.selectedMonster.scariness}"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:rating="3"/>
```

Comment: Can you share your fragment_detail.xml ?

Comment: @SulavTimsina, okay , please wait

Comment: please see the update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your binding files were not generated when you build your project.

To generate the binding files for the layout, the layout file has to start with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and close with

```
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```